# How can I find the roots for $x^4-18x^2-8x+21$ in a nice form?

Tags: equation-solving, polynomials

I'm trying to find the roots for $x^4-18x^2-8x+21$. Theoretically, one can show that it has four real roots. But the following line returns four complicated forms including complex numbers.

Is there a way to reduce the results to be in a nice form?

```
Solve[x^4-18x^2-8x+21==0,x]
```

[image]

Comment: I believe this is a case of [casus irreducibilis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casus_irreducibilis); i.e. the real solutions cannot be expressed without using the imaginary unit. The only "nice" way would be to make `Root` objects. If you apply `N` to the result (and `Chop` them), you will get a real number.

Comment: You can apply N[] to the solutions to get a numerical approximation and you'll see that, as you said, they're essentially real numbers (the imaginary parts are many orders of magnitude smaller than the real parts).  Not sure how to get an exact real solution, though.

Comment: What a nice form is depends on what you want to do with the results.  Do you just want to show them in a paper?  If yes, what is the purpose of showing them?  There aren't that many good reasons to write out the explicit solution of polynomial equations.  What is your reason?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your equation seems to be a [casus irreducibilis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casus_irreducibilis); the solutions cannot be expressed using only real numbers.

You can make them "nicer" by using [`Root`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Root.html) objects (try [`RootReduce`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RootReduce.html)).

```
RootReduce@Solve[x^4 - 18 x^2 - 8 x + 21 == 0, x]
```

> `{{x -> Root[21 - 8 #1 - 18 #1^2 + #1^4 &, 1]},
>   {x -> Root[21 - 8 #1 - 18 #1^2 + #1^4 &, 2]},
>   {x -> Root[21 - 8 #1 - 18 #1^2 + #1^4 &, 3]},
>   {x -> Root[21 - 8 #1 - 18 #1^2 + #1^4 &, 4]}}`

Or, you can use [`N`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/N.html) and [`Chop`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Chop.html) to get arbitrary-precision real numbers.

```
Chop@N@Solve[x^4 - 18 x^2 - 8 x + 21 == 0, x]
```

> `{{x -> -3.80007}, {x -> -1.42412}, {x -> 0.896691}, {x -> 4.3275}}`

Comment: Thanks a lot for the "casus irreducibilis".

Comment: `NRoots[x^4 - 18 x^2 - 8 x + 21, x]`

Answer (score 8):

To make the radical representation explicitly real, use the [`TargetFunctions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TargetFunctions.html) option with [`ComplexExpand`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComplexExpand.html)

```
roots = Solve[x^4 - 18 x^2 - 8 x + 21 == 0, x] // 
  ComplexExpand[#, TargetFunctions -> {Abs, Arg}] &

(*  {{x -> 
       -Sqrt[3 + 4*Cos[(1/3)*ArcTan[
                       Sqrt[39]/5]]] - 
         (1/2)*Sqrt[24 - 
               16*Cos[(1/3)*ArcTan[
                       Sqrt[39]/5]] - 
               8/Sqrt[3 + 4*Cos[(1/3)*
                         ArcTan[Sqrt[39]/5]]]]}, 
   {x -> 
       -Sqrt[3 + 4*Cos[(1/3)*ArcTan[
                       Sqrt[39]/5]]] + 
         (1/2)*Sqrt[24 - 
               16*Cos[(1/3)*ArcTan[
                       Sqrt[39]/5]] - 
               8/Sqrt[3 + 4*Cos[(1/3)*
                         ArcTan[Sqrt[39]/5]]]]}, 
   {x -> 
       Sqrt[3 + 4*Cos[(1/3)*ArcTan[
                     Sqrt[39]/5]]] - 
         (1/2)*Sqrt[24 - 
               16*Cos[(1/3)*ArcTan[
                       Sqrt[39]/5]] + 
               8/Sqrt[3 + 4*Cos[(1/3)*
                         ArcTan[Sqrt[39]/5]]]]}, 
   {x -> 
       Sqrt[3 + 4*Cos[(1/3)*ArcTan[
                     Sqrt[39]/5]]] + 
         (1/2)*Sqrt[24 - 
               16*Cos[(1/3)*ArcTan[
                       Sqrt[39]/5]] + 
               8/Sqrt[3 + 4*Cos[(1/3)*
                         ArcTan[Sqrt[39]/5]]]]}}  *)

roots // N

(*  {{x -> -3.80007}, {x -> -1.42412}, {x -> 0.896691}, {x -> 4.3275}}  *)
```

Comment: Trig expansions... They're never pretty... -- kinda cheating because inverse trig functions actually represent some complex functions: (e.g. `ArcTan[z] == Log[(I - z)/(I + z)]/(2 I)`)

Comment: @JHM - Using `N` the expressions evaluate without any imaginary artifacts and obviate the need to use `Chop`

Comment: Hmm, in 13.3 `ComplexExpand` just spits back the `Root` objects.

Comment: @GregHurst - The oldest version to which I currently have access is `"12.0.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (April 7, 2019)"` It also returns the `Root` expressions. Apparently, the change occurred between 2016 and 2019.

Answer (score 4):

You can obtain `Root` objects with

```
Solve[x^4 - 18 x^2 - 8 x + 21 == 0, x] // FullSimplify
```

or

```
Solve[x^4 - 18 x^2 - 8 x + 21 == 0, x] // RootReduce
```

but numerical roots are perhaps easier to understand.

```
NRoots[x^4 - 18 x^2 - 8 x + 21 == 0, x]
```

Convert the output of `NRoots` with `ToRules`, and pick the real roots with `Cases`. Plot the equation with red real roots. I wish I had `Manipulate` when I was studying calculus.

```
Manipulate[
   Module[{r = Cases[x/.{ToRules[NRoots[x^4 + a x^2 + b x + c == 0, x]]},_Real]},
      Plot[
         x^4 + a x^2 + b x + c, {x, -5, 5},
         PlotLabel -> ToString@TraditionalForm[x^4+a x^2+b x+c]<>"=0\n roots \[Rule] "<>ToString[r],
         Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.02], Point[Thread[List[r, 0]]]},
         Frame -> True, BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 16}, ImageSize -> 550]],
    {{a, -18.}, -20, 20, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
    {{b, -8.}, -20, 20, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
    {{c, 21.}, -100, 100, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image: polynomial roots]

Answer (score 4):

More like a comment.

```
sol = x /. Solve[x^4 - 18 x^2 - 8 x + 21 == 0, x] // N // Chop
```

> {-3.80007, -1.42412, 0.896691, 4.3275}

The roots may be approximated with

```
sol2 = RootApproximant[sol, 2]
```

[image]

which turn out to be quite decent approximations:

```
res = Table[x^4 - 18 x^2 - 8 x + 21 /. x -> sol2[[i]], {i, 1, 4}] // FullSimplify
```

[image]

```
N @ res
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Theres plenty of great answers here but I have some similar ideas I can give you..Maybe not as elegant or as advanced as others but it is straightforward.

```
 Clear[f, roots]
 f[x_] := x^4 - 18 x^2 - 8 x + 21
```

I would recommend NSolve because it is a numerical approximation, whereas Solve  is solving it explicitly

```
 roots = NSolve[f[x] == 0, x] 
 ={{x -> -3.80007}, {x -> -1.42412}, {x -> 0.896691}, {x -> 4.3275}}
```

Checks that roots are right

```
 f[x] /. roots//Chop
 ={0, 0, 0, 0}
```

I don't think this offers anymore assistance than what is already here, but oh well. You could even plot some of the roots on a graph of the curve..Say the 1st and 4th root..

```
 Clear[x1, x2]; 
 x1 = x /. roots[[1]]; 
 x2 = x /. roots[[4]];

 Clear[curve]; 
 curve = Plot[f[x], {x, -6, 6},
 AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}, Ticks -> None, BaseStyle -> {18, FontFamily -> "Georgia"}]; 

 PtLabel1 = Graphics[Text["( " <> ToString[x1] <> "," <> ToString[f[x1]] <> ")", {x1, f[x1] + 50}]]; 

 PtLabel2 = Graphics[Text["( " <> ToString[x2] <> "," <> ToString[f[x2]] <> ")", {x2, f[x2] + 50}]]; 

 pt1 = Graphics[{PointSize[0.02`], Point[{x1, f[x1]}]}]; 
 pt2 = Graphics[{PointSize[0.02`], Point[{x2, f[x2]}]}]; 
 Show[curve, PtLabel1, PtLabel2, pt1, pt2]
```