# Test exact radical output vs not exact radical output for `Sin[i]`

Tags: algebraic-manipulation, trigonometry

`FunctionExpand[Sin[3 Degree]]` outputs exact radical result, while `FunctionExpand[Sin[1 Degree]]` does not.

How can I write a test function that will take as argument this output result and return true if it's a radical expression and false if it's not?

`Map[{i, f} , Table[  FunctionExpand[Sin[i Degree]]   ,{i,0,90}]]`

returns `{{1, False}, ...,{3, True}..}`

Comment: `f = FreeQ[Sin]` should do for you.

Comment: Only multiples of `3 Degree` give a numerical result.

Comment: Do you want to test if Mathematica expands it in terms of radicals or whether it is at all possible to expand it in terms of radicals?  It appears that `Sin[Pi p/q]` can always be written in terms of radials for *any* rational `p/q` (I didn't know this before today, hence my long and now deleted answer about trying to figure out what `p/q` allows such expansion).

Comment: Here's some more on how you might solve in terms of radicals: http://www.maplesoft.com/applications/view.aspx?SID=7067&view=html

Comment: @Szabolcs in terms of the radical, not tied to this particular example.

Comment: You did not answer my question.  Do you want to test if Mathematica can do it?  Or whether it is possible to do it?

Comment: @Szabolcs mathematica

Comment: [A related question.](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/104223) Try this: `ToRadicals[RootReduce[FunctionExpand[Sin[1 °]]]]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not clear how you want integer and rational values handled.

```
test1 = FreeQ[#, _Sin | _Cos] &;

test2 = ! FreeQ[#, _Power] &;

(test1Result = 
   Select[{# Degree, FullSimplify[FunctionExpand[Sin[# Degree]]]} & /@ 
     Range[0, 90], test1]) // Length

(*  31  *)

(test2Result = 
   Select[{# Degree, FullSimplify[FunctionExpand[Sin[# Degree]]]} & /@ 
     Range[0, 90], test2]) // Length

(*  28  *)

Complement[test1Result, test2Result]

(*  {{0, 0}, {30 °, 1/2}, {90 °, 1}}  *)
```

Answer (score 2):

More like a comment.

*Mathematica* gives a numerical result, in form of a radical, for multiples of `3 Degree`, which looks like this:

```
Partition[#, 2] &@
  Table[{i Degree, FunctionExpand[Sin[i Degree]]}, {i, 3, 90, 3}] // 
 TableForm[#, TableDepth -> 2] &
```

[image]

Others remain unevaluated.

Let's denote

```
sin3 = FunctionExpand[Sin[3 Degree]]
```

Then one can use the identity

$$\sin(3 x)=3\sin x-4 \sin^3 x$$

to solve for $\sin x$ = `sin1`:

```
sin1 = s1 /. Solve[sin3 == 3 s1 - 4 s1^3, s1][[2]] // Simplify
```

[image]

Despite

```
sin1 // N // Chop
```

> 0.0174524

and

```
Sin[1. Degree]
```

> 0.0174524

agree, we see that there are imaginary units in `sin1`; I guess this is a case of [casus irreducibilis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casus_irreducibilis).

One can formally obtain `sin2` via

$$\sin(2 x)=2\sin x\cos x=2\sin x\sqrt{1-\sin^2 x}$$

```
sin2 = 2 sin1 Sqrt[1 - sin1^2] // Simplify
```

[image]

See also [this answer to another question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/131449/22013) for how to remove the imaginary unit `I` from `sin1` and `sin2`.