# How to simplify an output complex number?

Tags: matrix, simplifying-expressions, complex

I want to find the maximum root (in magnitude) to a determinant equal to zero, so I found the roots:

```
Solve[Det[({
 {2/π^2 - x, -1/(2 π^2), 1/(3 π^2)},
 {-1/(2 π^2), 1/(2 π^2) - x, -1/(6 π^2)},
 {1/(3 π^2), -1/(6 π^2), 2/(9 π^2) - x}
})] == 0, x]
```

[image]

The result was the following three complex roots:

[image]

which are not simplified and do not change with `Simplify`.

This results in not being able to find the magnitude of them using `Abs`.

What can I do to solve this problem?

How can I find the magnitude?

Comment: What do you mean by "simplify" in this case? If you want numerical answers, just apply `N`.

Comment: If you let the answer to the above be sol, then `Abs[N[sol[[#, 1, 2]]]] & /@ {1, 2, 3}` will give the magnitude of the three solutions.

Comment: Note that `PositiveDefiniteMatrixQ[{{2/π^2, -1/(2 π^2), 1/(3 π^2)}, {-1/(2 π^2), 1/(2 π^2), -1/(6 π^2)}, {1/(3 π^2), -1/(6 π^2), 2/(9 π^2) }}]` returns `True`, so the eigenvalues are then expected to be real and positive. `Eigenvalues[]` will directly return the desired results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
roots = Solve[
   Det[({{2/π^2 - x, -1/(2 π^2), 1/(3 π^2)}, {-1/(2 π^2), 
        1/(2 π^2) - x, -1/(6 π^2)}, {1/(3 π^2), -1/(6 π^2), 
        2/(9 π^2) - x}})] == 0, x];

N[Abs[x /. #]] & /@ roots

(*  {0.0138386, 0.224835, 0.0371452}  *)
```

[`SortBy`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SortBy.html) the numerical value of their absolute values

```
roots2 = SortBy[roots, N[Abs[x /. #]] &];

N[Abs[x /. #]] & /@ roots2

(*  {0.0138386, 0.0371452, 0.224835}  *)
```

Alternatively, first change their form to be explicitly real and then just `SortBy` their numeric values.

```
roots3 = SortBy[roots // ComplexExpand // Simplify, N];

N[x /. #] & /@ roots3

(*  {0.0138386, 0.0371452, 0.224835}  *)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
sol = Solve[ Det[{{2/π^2 - x, -1/(2 π^2), 1/(3 π^2)},
                  {-1/(2 π^2), 1/(2 π^2) - x, -1/(6 π^2)},
                  {1/(3 π^2), -1/(6 π^2), 2/(9 π^2) - x}}] == 0, x]
```

The numbers themselves **aren't complex**:

```
N @ sol
```

> {{x -> 0.0138386 + 2.46716*10^-17 I},
>
> {x -> 0.224835 + 0. I},
>
> {x -> 0.0371452 - 2.77556*10^-17 I}}

The imaginary parts are of the order of $10^{-17}$ - they are rounding errors, numerical artifacts. The exact solution given as `sol` is a [casus irreducibilis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casus_irreducibilis).

For example, with the first solution:

```
x1 = x /. sol[[1]]
```

one can do

```
reim1 = ReIm @ ComplexExpand[x1, TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}]
```

[image]

which is

```
FullSimplify @ reim1
```

> {Root[-2 + 21 #1 - 49 #1^2 + 18 #1^3 &, 1]/π^2, 0}

The imaginary part is equal to an **exact zero**. The real part is a root of a third-order polynomial, which can't be expressed with radicals because it's a casus irreducibilis, hence the `ArcTan` in `reim1`. See also [this thread](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/131438/how-can-i-find-the-roots-for-x4-18x2-8x21-in-a-nice-form), especially [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/131449/22013).

Eventually,

```
N @ reim1
```

> {0.0138386, 0.}

in agreement with `N @ sol`.

All of this applies also to `x2 = x /. sol[[2]]` and `x3 = x /. sol[[3]]`. And all three solutions are positive, so no need for `Abs`. So, the greatest value is `x /. sol // N // Chop // Max == 0.224835`.